# Using Visual Studio's 'Find', is it possible to exclude specific files from the search?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Let's say i refactored some code in my huge solution, now i want to be sure that there are no occurencies of my old code (including specific words in strings and so one).

Problem is, that i have a huge, automatically built file (imagine something like a 'compiled' app.js), which is allowed to contain string values of my old code.

With the 'Find' functionallity of Visual Studio, is it possible to skip this specific file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible way I could think off is **Look at these file types** field present in Find and Replace (Shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + F).

You could specify the file types with extensions or/and names. You could use multiple names separated by a semicolon.

Ex: Say you want to search in all XAML files & all CS files starting with A. You would enter this in the Look at these file types field: `*.xaml;A*.cs`

Comment: This answer really fits my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to ensure that your only matches are in that one file, you can check "Display file names only" option in "Find in Files", and verify that there is only that file name in the result pane.